# jQuery forward page or Servlet?

Tags: jquery, servlets, web-applications

I was wondering what the best practice is for changing pages. Is it best to allow a servlet to use a sendRedirect or simply allow jQuery/Javascript to do it?

So let's say I have a form that I want to submit and go to a new page. Would I just send the data from jQuery to the servlet, get a response and then forward the page via jQuery? Or would I send the information and get the servlet to forward the page?

Please let me know if you need any clarification. I'm more leaning to just letting jQuery handle page forwarding but I wanted to get the opinions of more experienced developers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're asking about page redirects - and if that's the question, have the server do it, not the client - client redirecting is generally frowned upon, especially for SEO

Client redirecting would involve setting window.location, I believe - server redirects just involve. 302 header, if I remember the number correctly

Comment: As stated by Adil, if I can't redirect a user from my servlet, how would I use the web server to change a page?

Comment: Using a form is not AJAX - I assumed you were just submitting a plain old form - which the server can then return a 302 redirect

Comment: You're correct, I have to create a form I believe. I'm essentially trying to have a <select> menu contain a tableID and a link, have it clicked and then have it forward to a new page. So I just have to change it to submit a form instead.

Answer (score 0):

*If you send data using* `ajax` you will not be able to redirect user from within your servlet,
For that you need to redirect user from you script (*once you get response from servlet*).

If you submit your form without ajax - You should be able to redirect user from your servlet.

Comment: As stated by jQueryRocks, if client-side redirects are frowned upon, how would I communicate with my servlet to redirect a page without using jQuery?

Comment: As already said.. IF you use ajax to submit form,You can **not** redirect from your servlet...But if you are not using ajax, You have full control over redirection using your servlet